# SSIS 2008 SCript Component DT_TIMESTAMP to DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl

I am reading a list of files in a VB.net script source component to create a list of filenames and the `LastWriteDate` for a list of files.  The `LastWriteDate` is held as a DateTime in the script source and output to a `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` which is stored in a destination Recordset.

I stuck a viewer on the dataflow between the source and destination which shows the `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` holds a value of `2018-01-15 15:55:05.765` for the first file.

In the Control Flow I then perform a ForEach loop over the recordset.
In it I have a variable of the type DateTime that is mapped to the `DT_TIMESTAMP`.

Inside the ForEach I have a script Component that maps the `DT_TIMESTAMP` into the component.
The component retrieves the `DT_TIMESTAMP` into a DateTime variable but stores it as 
`1/15/2018 3:55:06 PM`.

Not only does the format change but the precision as well.
I’m a bit confused over what is going on here but I assume the full date and time in the `DT_TIMESTAMP` is still available in my second script but I’m not clear how to get at it.

Is there a way of setting the DateTime variable in my script to show to the same precision as the `DT_TIMESTAMP`?  Maybe I need to define the receiving script variable to something other than DateTime i.e. a `DT_TIMESTAMP` equivalent?

Is there a way of preventing the DateTime variable in the script component rounding the value from `DT_TIMESTAMP` so it is converted to `1/15/2018 3:55:05 PM`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most accurate way to do this would be to import `2018-01-15 15:55:05.765` into a varchar variable. Then if you need to do date/time calculation in the package with the variable, convert it to DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 and it will keep the exact value of `2018-01-15 15:55:05.765`. If you need to insert the value into SQLServer, insert it as a `DATETIME` type and you'll get the value of `2018-01-15 15:55:05.767`. This is due to a limitation of the datetime datatype.

from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql):
datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

Answer (score 0):

The greatest precision of a date data type in SSIS is:

DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 A timestamp structure that consists of year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and fractional seconds. The fractional seconds have a maximum scale of 7 digits.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a separate answer because I think this might actually help with your problem. The other answer just details the precision of a data type.

I am not sure what you are attempting to do with your foreach loop, but I would suggest doing row level work in your original dataflow.

The greatest precision of a datetime variable is second.